# TypeError: _ReanimatedModule.default.animateNextTransition is not a function in React-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

#### Current Behavior

[image: 스크린샷 2019-05-30 오후 5 06 46]

> **When you click on the text, you get an error with the title.**

#### Expected Behavior

I hoped that the screen would move smoothly without being cut off or showing a white screen.

#### How to reproduce

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import createAnimatedSwitchNavigator from "react-navigation-animated-switch";
import { Transition } from "react-native-reanimated";
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
import A from "./A";
import B from "./B";

const MySwitch = createAnimatedSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Home: A,
    Other: B
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    headerMode: "none"
  },
  {
    // The previous screen will slide to the bottom while the next screen will fade in
    transition: (
      <Transition.Together>
        <Transition.Out
          type="slide-bottom"
          durationMs={400}
          interpolation="easeIn"
        />
        <Transition.In type="fade" durationMs={500} />
      </Transition.Together>
    )
  }
);
const HomeScreenRouter = createAppContainer(MySwitch);

export default HomeScreenRouter;
```

A.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";

export default class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Other")}>
          Open up App.js to start working on your app!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

B.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class B extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>B screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

#### Your Environment

| react-navigation |  "^3.11.0"

| react-native     | "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz"

| node             |  v10.16.0

| react-native-reanimated | "^1.0.1"

| react-navigation-animated-switch | "^0.2.0"

| npm or yarn      | 6.9.0

Please help me a lot

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not currently available in sdk 32. sdk 33 is coming  soon.

this is documented in [the readme](https://github.com/react-navigation/animated-switch#installation)